# Batch file that will modify date in txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a line in a text file that I'm trying to modify using a batch file. The line in this case is the `lastexportdate=2014-01-01`. I'm trying to get the batch file to modify this from

```
lastexportdate=2014-01-01
```

to

```
lastexportdate= Current timestamp.
```

Is this possible to have this equal the timestamp of my computer?  Not certain how to go about tackling this, so if anyone could help that would be awesome. I'm using Windows 7.

File contents below:

```
root.footer=</CREDITEXPORT>
root.header=<CREDITEXPORT>
emailaddronsuccess=test@test.com
emailaddronerror=test@test.com
rerunexportdate=2014-09-06
errorfilelocation=C:\\ 
lastexportdate=2014-01-01
xmloutputlocation=C:\\
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem getting current time stamp
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:var t=new Date();var dd=t.getDate();var mm=t.getMonth()+1;var yyyy=t.getFullYear();if(dd^<10) dd='0'+dd;if(mm^<10) mm='0'+mm;close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=));""


:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd %endJS%'
) do set cds=%%N
echo cds=%cds%


rem processing the file
rem set the location of the file
set "content_file=c:\some.file"
break>temp.file
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%content_file%") do (

  if "%%a" NEQ "lastexportdate" echo %%a=%%b>>temp.file
  if "%%a" EQU "lastexportdate" echo %%a=%cds%>>temp.file
)
```

Not tested.Just change the location of the content_file and check if the created temp.file is ok.
To replace the file add `move temp.file "%content_file%"` at the end.

Comment: Awesome. Just tried this out and it works like a charm. I really do appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Hey npocmaka what would I need to do in order to have yesterdays timestamp entered ? Would that be a simple modification that I could make ?